# how to print qr code in p25 blue bamboo using android?

Tags: android

I would really appreciate if you can help me with this little problem I`ve had for a while now.

The thing is that when I print an image or qr code I only gets a lot of 'y' as result.

Here the function that I used to print qr code:

```
printQR() {
    QRCodeEncoder qrCodeEncoder = new QRCodeEncoder("stringQR", 
            null, 
            "TEXT_TYPE", 
            BarcodeFormat.QR_CODE.toString(), 
            250);
    try {
        Bitmap bitmapQR = qrCodeEncoder.encodeAsBitmap();   // Here 
        int size = bitmapQR.getRowBytes() * bitmapQR.getHeight();
        ByteBuffer byteBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(size);
        bitmapQR.copyPixelsToBuffer(byteBuffer);
        byte[] byteArray = byteBuffer.array();

        // I think here is the problem
        byte[] formats = {(byte)0x1B,(byte)0x58,(byte)0x31,(byte)0x20,(byte)0xFA};
        byte[] bytes = new byte[formats.length + byteArray.length];

        System.arraycopy(formats, 0, bytes, 0, formats.length);
        System.arraycopy(byteArray, 0, bytes, formats.length, byteArray.length);

        try {
            BluetoothService.write(bytes);
            BluetoothService.write("\n\n".getBytes());                
        }  catch (IOException e) {
               e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }  catch (WriterException e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public QREncoder(String data, Bundle bundle, String type, String format, int dimension) {
    this.dimension = dimension;
    encoded = encodeContents(data, bundle, type, format);
}

private boolean encodeContents(String data, Bundle bundle, String type, String formatString) {
    format = null;
    if (formatString != null) {
        try {
            format = BarcodeFormat.valueOf(formatString);
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException iae) { }
    }
    if (format == null || format == BarcodeFormat.QR_CODE) {
        this.format = BarcodeFormat.QR_CODE;
        encodeQRCodeContents(data, bundle, type);
    } else if (data != null && data.length() > 0) {
        contents = data;
        displayContents = data;
        title = "Text";
    }
    return contents != null && contents.length() > 0;
}

public Bitmap encodeAsBitmap() throws WriterException {
    if (!encoded) return null;
    Map<EncodeHintType, Object> hints = null;
    String encoding = guessAppropriateEncoding(contents);
    if (encoding != null) {
        hints = new EnumMap<EncodeHintType, Object>(EncodeHintType.class);
        hints.put(EncodeHintType.CHARACTER_SET, encoding);
    }

    MultiFormatWriter writer = new MultiFormatWriter();
    BitMatrix result = writer.encode(contents, format, dimension, dimension, hints);
    int width = result.getWidth();
    int height = result.getHeight();
    int[] pixels = new int[width * height];
    // All are 0, or black, by default
    for (int y = 0; y < height; y++) {
        int offset = y * width;
        for (int x = 0; x < width; x++) {
            pixels[offset + x] = result.get(x, y) ? BLACK : WHITE;
        }
    }

    Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    bitmap.setPixels(pixels, 0, width, 0, 0, width, height);
    return bitmap;
}
```

The size of the QR image is 250 x 250, thats why I put 0x20 0xFA in byte[] formats

Comment: Have you tried ZXing? It can build customized Bitmap from your QR or BAR code.

Comment: yes, I created the QR code using ZXing, and I can see it in a ImageView, but the problem is when I try to print it